# How Spring Boot redirect http to https with HTTP 301?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, spring-boot

In my spring boot project,i add https support,when i `curl -I http://127.0.0.1:80`,i got `HTTP/1.1 302`,how can i redirect with HTTP 301.
this is my config,in my code has some comment maybe useful.
Anybody can help me?very thankful!

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory =
                new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
                    @Override
                    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                        SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                        securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                        SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                        collection.addPattern("/*");
                        securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                        context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
                    }
                };
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createHttpConnector());
        return factory;
    }

    private Connector createHttpConnector() {
        //org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector,in this source code i saw a method named createResponse(),
        //this method return an org.apache.catalina.connector.Response,
        //in this response has a method sendRedirect(),there is a constant set httpstatus 302
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return container -> {
            Ssl ssl = new Ssl();
            ssl.setKeyStore("classpath:***.jks");
            ssl.setKeyStorePassword("***");
            container.setSsl(ssl);
            container.setPort(443);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a Tomcat-specific question and not directly related to Boot (unless the answer is "use a different servlet container").

Comment: ok,i just modify the tomcat resource solved my problem.Thanks.